# assigning vector

Tags: c++, vector

how I can assign v[i] to an series of integers  ( type of v is vector ) without initially filling inside

Comment: and what is the type of your series of integer ? ? ?

Comment: take int from stdin (with temporary holder int p ;)  and store into v[i],

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have anything that has the traits of an iterator you can use vector's assign method:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.assign( iterStart, iterEnd );
```

- iterStart should be such that *iterStart is the first value you want to add.
- iterEnd should be one past the end,  it is a terminating  condition
- ++iter would move you to the next iterator in the input series.

I don't know what you mean by assign v[i] though. You cannot assign an element to a series. If you want to write the series at a location into an existing vector you can use insert instead of assign.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean initializing std::vector to a series of integers?

```
int i[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<int> myVector(i, i+ (sizeof(i)/sizeof(int)));
```

If you meant to create a vector of some elements so you can perform the assignment using their index values. Here, the following statement declares and initializes a vector with its elements being default initialized to 0.

```
std::vector<int> myVector(5); // constructs a vector of size five integers.

for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    myVector[x] = i[x];     // assign values using subscript [..]
```

But I think the even better way to go would be as @CashCow mentioned in his answer.

Also, note that you can also pre-allocate memory to add elements into the vector with avoiding any repeated memory allocations.

For example:

```
std::vector<int> myVector; // empty vector for integers
myVector.reserve(5); // pre-allocates memory for five integers

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // now, you can add your elements
    myVector.push_back(i);
```

It is usually a good idea to pre-allocate memory if you know the size of elements i.e in case of large number of elements when the performance is an important factor.

Comment: It's not just allocate, but also construct that many `value_type` objects. Not just sizeof(int) * 5 allocation alone happens but 5 integers are created and stored.

Answer (score 1):

common way of adding items is calling std::vector<>push_back() method.

```
std::vector<int> myVector;
myVector.push_back(5);
myVector.push_back(10);
myVector.push_back(3);
```